# Switch JSP behavior with Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm intendig to have one JSP for two types of list: one that has Administrator fields and other that dont. But I think it would be good if I had only one list that would switch behavior accordingly to the user requesting the list, making maintenance easier.

Is this a good Idea? If so, help me solve my problem:

I have a JSP with all the list attributes, but some are inside a

```
<c:if test="${BooleanAttributeFromController}"></c:if>
```

In controller, I have two Mappings: one from default list, that normal users does have access and one for admin list, that only admin have access. In this second list, this boolean attribute is passed if the user has admin rigths (double security). Im using

```
model.addAttribute("BooleanAttributeFromController", new Boolean(true));
```

but its showing to admin list attributes, even though it is loading the list the correct way (its using the correct mapping and not redirecting, as it is configured to happen if the user has no admin rights).

Both the mappings redirect to the same jsp, only with an extra attribute. Why does it not work?

***More complete code below:***

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping("getAnalysisList")
    public String listAnalysis(Model model, HttpSession session){
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("userId").toString());
        List<Analysis> analysisList = dao.getAnalysisListPerUser(userId);
        model.addAttribute("analysisList", analysisList);
        return "analysis/analysisList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("listAllAnalysis")
    public String listAllAnalysis(Model model, HttpSession session){
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("userId").toString());
        if(userDao.isAdmin(userId)){
            List<Analysis> analysisList = dao.getAnalysisListAdmin();
            model.addAttribute("analysisList", analysisList);
            model.addAttribute("completeList", new Boolean(true));
            return "analysis/analysisList";
        }else{
            return "redirect:index";
        }
    }
```

**JSP table list:**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th><spring:message code="analysisList.Filename"></spring:message></th>
            <th><spring:message code="analysisList.DateInserted"></spring:message></th>
            <c:if test="${empty completeList}">
<!--            ToDo: Find how to toggle special list for admin type -->
                <th><spring:message code="analysisList.User" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="analysisList.Expiration" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="analysisList.Flag" /></th>
            </c:if>
            <th><spring:message code="analysisList.ReportLink" /></th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSP has a little known mechanism called Tag Files, where you can extract parts of your page to a component library, and call it with different parameters. Sounds like that may be what you need:

[JEE Tutorial 5: Tag Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html)